# can pandoc convert txt to latex input files?

Tags: pandoc, scrbook

i've just installed Pandoc on Kubuntu 14.04 and envision using it on a sort of homebrew markdown.txt files that will be used as chapters in a book (using koma script scrbook).  The book already has a master file and preamble.  I'd just like to somehow customize Pandoc to convert my own format, a sort of markdown.

Was pandoc designed for that (customization) or can only export it to a report like document with computer modern fonts?  If so, how do I tell pandoc to not define a class etc, since my preamble does all that.

Comment: http://pandoc.org/README.html#custom-writers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc defines the preamble etc only if you set the standalone option '-s'. Leave it out and you are good to go.